# Is there any difference between these ways of importing in Python?

Tags: python

Is it the same in Python ?

```
import time.sleep
```

and

```
from time import sleep
```

Can anyone describe what is the difference between those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `time.sleep` is a module or a package, then `import time.sleep` and `from time import sleep` are almost the same.

Both will import `time` and `time.sleep`, but they will bind different things to local variables.

In a way, you could say that this:

```
from time import sleep
```

is more-or-less the same as this:

```
import time.sleep
sleep = time.sleep
del time
```

Because, after `from time import sleep`, there is no local variable `time`, but there is a local variable `sleep`.

---

On the other hand, if it is a class, rather than a module, there is a difference: you can do `from module_name import ClassName`, but you cannot `import module_name.ClassName`.

Comment: I get it well. Thanks. zvone